# JSON element selection using jq - how to do?

Tags: json, jq

I am following the examples online when trying to select elements of that array but something very weird happens.

When I run
`.issuesData.issues[]`  it displays the array as expected.  Fine.

Then I try to select only the nodes with `statusId == 10270`.  this would give me, as expected result, just the last node.

But the result is the array of the 2 objects having all elements assigned with `statusId = 10270`.

`.issuesData.issues[].statusId="10270"`

If I try a slightly different approach like that

`.issuesData.issues[].statusId=="10270"`

I get an array

```
false
true
```

and this makes sense because only the second elements fits he criteria.  But what I am trying to get is just the element itself or at least the "key"
The JSON object is like below.

```
{
  "issuesData": {
    "issues": [
      {
        "id": 3619364,
        "key": "AIG-1992",
        "hidden": false,
        "typeId": "1",
        "summary": "XXXXXX",
        "priorityId": "2",
        "done": false,
        "assignee": "XXXX",
        "assigneeName": "XXXX",
        "hasCustomUserAvatar": false,
        "autoUserAvatar": {
          "letter": "B",
          "color": "#d39c3f"
        },
        "color": "#ff0000",
        "epicId": "3557134",
        "epic": "AIG-1",
        "estimateStatisticRequired": false,
        "statusId": "10370",
        "fixVersions": [
          120044
        ],
        "projectId": 49202
      },
      {
        "id": 3617950,
        "key": "AIG-1938",
        "hidden": false,
        "typeId": "1",
        "summary": "YYYYYY",
        "priorityId": "2",
        "done": false,
        "assignee": "YYYY",
        "assigneeName": "YYY",
        "hasCustomUserAvatar": false,
        "autoUserAvatar": {
          "letter": "F",
          "color": "#7bc1a1"
        },
        "color": "#ff0000",
        "epicId": "3658470",
        "epic": "AIG-574",
        "estimateStatisticRequired": false,
        "statusId": "10270",
        "fixVersions": [],
        "projectId": 49202
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: `.issuesData.issues[]` doesn't "display the array". It displays objects that were items in the array. Use `select` to filter the output, and use that boolean you produced as condition: `.issuesData.issues[] | select(.statusId=="10270")`. To then only get "the key", add `.key`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want a stream of objects having a key with the string value `"10270"`:

```
.issuesData.issues[] | select(.statusId == "10270")
```

Assuming you want an *array* containing all matching objects:

```
.issuesData.issues | map(select(.statusId == "10270"))
```

Assuming you want to modify the original structure to only keep the matching objects:

```
.issuesData.issues |= map(select(.statusId == "10270"))
```

If you only want the ids of the objects having the specified statusId:

```
.issuesData.issues[] | select(.statusId == "10270").id
```

If you need the ids as JSON array:

```
.issuesData.issues | map(select(.statusId == "10270").id)
```